# Best way to get home launcher packagename and start it

Tags: android

I encountered a problem about how to get home launcher packagename.
In android , there are two type of home launcher:

1. orginal launcher
2. 3-third launcher ,such as go-launcher or OEM

So, we can't use specified packagename to start it.
Finally, I figure out a solution. 
Is there any other better way to do this?

```
    //find out the package with ACTION_MAIN & CATEGORY_HOME
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> ris = (List<ResolveInfo>) pm.queryIntentActivities(i,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    Log.i("", ris.size() + "");
    //seletc the first one , doc says the first one is the home launcher currently
    if (ris != null && ris.size() > 0) {
        String pkg = ris.get(0).activityInfo.packageName;
        Log.i("HOME PKG NAME ", pkg);
        //start it 
        i.setClassName(ris.get(0).activityInfo.packageName, ris.get(0).activityInfo.name);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Thanks for https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/-5aGSOdwJ-8

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Intent with Category `CATEGORY_HOME` and Action `ACTION_MAIN`.

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Comment: Sood,Thanks for your reply.I test the code, and it works fine. This is the simple way to start home `Activity` but if I want to konw packagename ? Such as I want to detect whether `HOME Activity` run foreground now.