# how to show applications screen programatically

Tags: android

How can I show Applications screen on click of a button programatically,
I dont want home screen, I want applications screen where we see installed apps.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    switch (position) {
        case Applications:
            break;
        case Camera:
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                 android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivity(cameraIntent);
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
i SEE EVERY ONE GIVING A WAY TO SHOW APPLICATIONS IN SETTINGS..I want the normal applications screen where from I can launch diffferent apps.

Comment: your question is not clear you want to start default launcher from where u can able to start other apps?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K Yes. If we consider a samsung phone or so, there will be an icon for apps. If we click that icon, we see all the apps in a grid . I want this screen programatically

Answer (score 0):

Launch an Intent with the Action [ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings. ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

However, this works only on API 9 and above. Use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings. ACTION_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

For devices below API 9.

EDIT:

In answer to your edit:

> I want the normal applications screen where from I can launch diffferent apps.

There is no way to do this. Not all launchers display their apps in a list, or require the list to be opened separately from the launcher. There is no documented Intent for this. At best, you can launch the home screen using:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Comment: No, It takes me to the settings screen and apps in it. But I should go to the screen where from I can launch the app. The normal Apps listing screen

Comment: @SaiDinakarGM There is no documented Intent for doing that. You may only launch the homescreen app as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15551627/1069068).

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS, 0));`

This link can be helpful: [android.provider.Settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS)